# Laravel Parse `geometry` data type from `MYSQL` database to the original coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have a `geometry` (geometry is the data type and column name) column in the MYSQL table called `geofences`, and I need to parse or convert this `geometry` value to a readable array of coordinates. So I have an approach already done what I want but I believe there is a better way out there to do it here's my approach.

here's how I select my geometry value from my database

```
 DB::raw("(ST_AsText(geometry)) AS `geometry`")
```

The QUERY output

```
"POLYGON((46.646748 24.562727,46.645079 24.561795,46.643556 24.563615,46.64539 24.564747,46.646748 24.562727,46.646748 24.562727))"
```

I added an accessor in the `Geofence` model.

```
public function getGeometryAttribute($value): array
    {
        $slice = Str::between($value, '((', '))');
        if ($this->shape_type == 'circle') {
            $slice = Str::between($value, '(', ')');
        }

        return collect(explode(',', $slice))->map(function ($point) {
            $points = explode(' ', $point);

            return [
                'longitude' => $points[0],
                'latitude'  => $points[1],
            ];
        })->toArray();
    }
```

The output as I expect

```
array:6 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "46.646748"
    "latitude" => "24.562727"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "46.645079"
    "latitude" => "24.561795"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "46.643556"
    "latitude" => "24.563615"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "46.64539"
    "latitude" => "24.564747"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "46.646748"
    "latitude" => "24.562727"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "46.646748"
    "latitude" => "24.562727"
  ]
]
```

If someone knows a better way to handle this case kindly advise me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future visits I figured it out you have to use `ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry)` instead of `ST_AsText(geometry)`  this query will return the `GeoJson` object `{"type":"Polygon", "coordinates":[[[46.646748,24.562727],[46.645079,24.561795],[46.643556,24.563615],[46.64539,24.564747],[46.646748,24.562727],[46.646748,24.562727]]]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judge Jules found the issue in comments.

```
DB::raw("(ST_AsText(geometry)) AS `geometry`")
```

Should be:

```
DB::raw("(ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry)) AS `geometry`")
```

The output is now:

```
{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":
    [
        [
            [46.646748,24.562727],
            [46.645079,24.561795],
            [46.643556,24.563615],
            [46.64539,24.564747],
            [46.646748,24.562727],
            [46.646748,24.562727]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. What this means? Where is the table name in this query?